# CSS: how do I fix my hyperlink alignment issue?

Tags: css, alignment

I have two links: shopper and store. Both of these links are in there own separate left and right floats. The Store link is supposed to be in a right float, but it snaps out of its div when adding a border style to the left float. How do I get it back into place? Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/JuCKU/ for an example.

I completely forgot to update jfiddle with the new code.  http://jsfiddle.net/JuCKU/3/

firefox is having the alignment issue while google chrome seems to render the layout correctly.

Comment: First off, did you mean your last CSS rule selector to be `#shopper, #store`? I also don't see anything wrong with the layout on Chrome 17.

Comment: Can you puts a fiddle up where the layout breaks? I added a border to #shopper but everything stayed in place.

Comment: @Hersha have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/JuCKU/3/

Comment: I'm not seeing anything broken in [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JuCKU/) using Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the width from 50% to 49%. Since you have a border, it takes up space and by giving each div a width of 50%, the total is a bit too wide and the second div pop down a bit. Or get rid of the border.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JuCKU/5/)** Example

Change

```
#shopper, #store
{
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

To:

```
#shopper, #store
{
    width: 49%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation.  Even though I dislike IE I still would like to incorporate IE users.  Changing the width seems more of a universal browser fix.

Answer (score 1):

<s>It's a rounding issue</s>. It's not a rounding issue, 50% + 50% + 1px border is more than 100%. Making the width slightly less than 50% is a quick fix.

Change this:

```
#shopper, #store
{
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

for this:

```
#shopper, #store
{
    width: 49.9999%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JuCKU/4/

Comment: It's really more of a box model issue. The border is drawn outside of the element thus making it bigger than what you define it as so the actual width of the div should be 50% - (width of the border). You can make the border be drawn inside the element but i forget how to do that right now.

Comment: @Hersha that's what I realised, hence the edit. Regarding making the border render inside the box are you thinking of `box-sizing`? http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing

Comment: Yeah thats the property I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the border increases the overall size of the boxes to 50%+1px, so together their combined width is greater than 100% and something's gotta give.

You can use the CSS3 property `box-sizing:border-box` to incorporate the border into the total 50% width, or more specifically -moz-box-sizing in Firefox, -webkit-box-sizing in Chrome/Safari and simply box-sizing in Opera.  Unfortunately IE doesn't yet support this.

So add this to your code.

```
#shopper, #store {
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

More info - http://www.css3.info/preview/box-sizing/

As mentioned by others the bulletproof solution across all browsers is to reduce the width of your boxes to fractionally less than 50%.

Answer (score 1):

simple give `margin-right:-1px` in your `shopper div`

```
#shopper
{
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-right:-1px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/JuCKU/6/

**OR**

you can use css3 `box-sizing` property for this but it's work till `IE8` & above.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/JuCKU/7/

Comment: The problem with applying a negative margin is that the rest of your content gets shifted with it. This could make things look funny if you have any other borders that line up with it.

Comment: @Hersha i give two answers first as per OP Mark-Up & second if OP put anything new on it.

Comment: I know. Just pointing out the side effect of your first method not trying to discount it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Give the divs some  widths

see http://jsfiddle.net/JuCKU/1/